# The arrow buttons in Python tkinter spinbox update the color and text of a label using textvariable but not the Return key

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I've looked for my problem in the FAQ and found some hints.
But they couldn't solve my problem.
Therefore here is my question:

I've written a GUI in Python 3.8 which uses three spinboxes for the 3 values of RGB colors.
At the start it shows the three values (127, 127, 127) a gray color.
The two labels on the right side show the color and the hex value.

By using the two arrow buttons of the spinboxes and keeping them pressed, the color and the hex value of the two labes will change simultaneously.

My problem is the "Return" key does not update the color and the hex value, since they are not using textvariable and StringVar() in a normal way.

The hex value must be generated before showing and the color of the label must be set in an update function.

And this is the issue I think with which the "Return" key does not work.

I've used also the bind option for the spinboxes which doesn't update immadiately the value afte entering by hand in the field an press the Reurn key.

After I use the arrow buttons of the spinboxes or the arrow keys on the keyboard it changes the color and the hex value of the labels.

If you have any idea or see where I'm doing the wrong step, any advise is appreciated.

Here is code to illustrate the problem:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

val_str = StringVar()

color_bg = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'black', 'orange', 'cyan']
color_fg = ['white', 'yellow', 'cyan', 'white', 'blue', 'red']

def update_val():
    global val_str, fg_col, bg_col

    var_int = int(spin.get())
    val_str.set(str(var_int))

    label['bg'] = color_bg[(var_int%6)-1]
    label['fg'] = color_fg[(var_int%6)-1]

spin = Spinbox(root,
               from_=1,
               to=100,
               width=10,
               textvariable=val_str,
               command=update_val,
               font='Helvetica 30 bold',
               justify=CENTER,
               fg='red',
               bg='yellow')
spin.pack()

label = Label(root,
              width=10,
              textvariable=val_str,
              font='Helvetica 30 bold',
              fg='red',
              bg='white')
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please try to reduce the code down to a [mcve]. If the question is about a spinbox, we don't need much more than a single spinbox, and just enough extra code to illustrate the problem.

Comment: What should I reduce. I've seen questions with much longer codes.
I’ve pasted my whole working script. The only thing you need is to copy that an put it into a file and run it.
As long as you use the arrow buttons of spinbox or of keyboard, it works fine and the two right labels are updated with background color and the other with value immediately.

Comment: BTWBy double clicking on each value in spinboxes and entering new value the bg-color and the value of the two labels will not be updated. You have either to use the arrow buttons of the spinbox or of the keyboard to update them.
I've written a small program with one label and one spinbox. It works fine because the textvariable is used directly between label and spinbox without any intermediate operation.
But in my case the label color and the label value are processed before and then are used. If I take some part of the code it cannot reproduce the wrong behaviour of my code.

Comment: @Bryan  OK as you wisch here is one spinbox and one label.

Comment: When the user starts typing in the spinbox, would you prefer that the color is always in sync with the value or should it only change when they press the return key? For example, if the value is 100 and the user deletes the trailing zero so that the value is 10, should the color change or wait until they press return?

Comment: @Bryan  yes, the changes should take effekt, after the user has pressed the enter key.

Comment: _only_ after pressing the enter key? I just want to make sure, as the answer leads to different ways to solve the problem. You say you've tried using `bind`, but your code doesn't show it. Can you show what you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the color to be updated when the user types in the spinbox entry field and then presses the enter key, you need to bind a function to the `<Return>` event.

You can either create a new function that accepts the event parameter that tkinter automatically sends, modify your existing function to accept the event parameter, or use `lambda` or `functools.partial` to accept and ignore the parameter.

Here's how to modify the existing function:

```
def update_val(event=None):
    global val_str, fg_col, bg_col

    var_int = int(spin.get())
    val_str.set(str(var_int))

    label['bg'] = color_bg[(var_int%6)-1]
    label['fg'] = color_fg[(var_int%6)-1]
...
spin.bind("<Return>", update_val)
```

Here's how to use `lambda` without modifying `update_val`:

```
spin.bind("<Return>", lambda event: update_val())
```

Comment: In my original script lines 139, 158 and 177, you will see the three bind commands with the spinbox for 3 colors R, G and B.  
As you suggested, I've used your last version with "lambda" as I don't need to change anything in my function and it works perfectly. Because I used the name of the function and not the function itself. I got the error message as below:  
TypeError: update_value_G() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given  
I will try your first version and going to modify the update function to learn two ways of manipulating the behavior of a spinbox.